# How to scroll horizontally in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I've a basic table layout that gets cut when viewed in mobile. Horizontal scrolling doesn't appear to work. The table is basically stuck and cutoff. Only vertical scrolling works. Is it possible to enable horizontal scrolling in Jquery Mobile?

Screenshot on desktop browser:

[image]

Screenshot on mobile:

[image]

Screenshot on resized desktop browser (horizontal scroll also doesn't work):

[image]

Sample code:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
<table> 
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>foo</td>        
        </tr>
</table>            
</div>
```

BTW if I remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` horizontal scrolling works but then the mobile's width has become big and the purpose of mobile view is quite defeated. Any workaround?

Comment: Consider uploading a screenshot for us to be able to better assist you. You could try wrapping it with a DIV tag with `overflow-x:auto;`

Comment: @Coby that didn't work, also updated my question w/ screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could set your `viewport` meta tag to a specific `width` that matches your content. That way you can limit how wide your page becomes.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=600px, initial-scale=1">
```

In a general sense this is frowned-upon since it's not responsive like `width=device-width` is but in this context it sounds like what you need.

**NOTE:** This is untested, I've never used a pixel value for the `width` declaration in a `viewport` tag before. My understanding is that this should make everything appear by default, then the user can zoom in/out to make the text easier to read.

The well-supported alternative is to use faux-scrolling with JavaScript. There are pre-made solutions like iScroll 4 (others are out there too but they're escaping me at the moment).

If you're interested, here is the Apple documentation for the `viewport` meta tag: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html (which Apple started using before other browser makers)